# Facing problem while upgrading my ruby version using RVM: This error is showing again and again when i opened the file

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

```
92 warnings generated.
linking shared-object socket.bundle
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
5 warnings generated.
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2

Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/jigyasasharma/.rvm/log/1690787741_ruby- 
3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the 
installation.
```

I was using chatGPT, but I'm unable to find the problem.
Help me to find the solution as I installed ruby through rbenv, RVM and Homebrew as well and all of them are of different versions.

Comment: What does the `/Users/jigyasasharma/.rvm/log/1690787741_ruby- 
3.0.0/make.log` log file look like?

Comment: Btw. Using different Ruby versions managers at the same time will certainly cause issues. I suggest uninstalling all installed Ruby versions and all those version managers. And then start from scratch with one version manager, e.g. rbenv and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Hombrew which implies macOS. There are a number of issues right now compiling against libressl or openssl@3. More importantly, pkgconfig can't currently find what it needs when passed the `--with-openssl-dir=` configuration flag for certain Ruby versions.

For more information, you can review this [ruby-install issue #458](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/458), which includes some work-arounds involving the explicit setting of environment variables for OpenSSL. Alternatively, with Ruby >= 3.1.1, this supposedly works for some people with ruby-install:

```bash
ruby-install -U
ruby-install ruby 3.2.2 --with-openssl-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
```

You could always build with a different version manager if rvm doesn't have a similar set of work-arounds available. Your mileage may also vary depending on OS and Ruby versions, processor, Ruby version manager or compilation process, and other dependencies. It should certainly help you narrow down the problem, though.